# What does the printed out result mean. System.nanoTime() in Java

Tags: java, frame-rate

I don't understand what i get from printing out `timeStarted`, then printing out `getTime()`. What is it that i am printing out? What does the printed out values mean?

I have just began learning java and are trying to understand how to work with frame rates.

**Time.java**

```
public class Time {
    public static double timeStarted = System.nanoTime();
    public static double getTime() { return (System.nanoTime() - timeStarted) * 10E-9; }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time time = new Time();
        System.out.println(time.timeStarted);
        System.out.println(time.getTime());
    }
}
```

**Console:**

```
4.24512563119081E14
0.01404352
```

Comment: `timeStarted` is assigned when the class `Time` loads so that is the time when it loaded. Then the method `getTime` tells you how much time have passed since the class was loaded. Also notice that you don't need an instance to access that method since it is `static`.

Comment: Tip: Java provides a tool to help with microbenchmarking: [*jmh*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.nanoTime()` returns the current value of the most precise available system timer in nanoseconds. The value returned represents nanoseconds passed since some fixed but arbitrary time.

`System.nanoTime()` has nothing to do with dates and time-of-day. `System.nanoTime()` is an ongoing count of passing nanoseconds, nothing more.

Multiplying the return value of `System.nanoTime()` with `10E-9` will yield the current count in seconds, times 10. (To properly convert to seconds, you would have to multiply by `1e-9`. I am guessing this was the original intention?)

Since you are substracting the current count from the starting count, the return value of `getTime()` will represent the amount of time that has passed since the `Time`-class was loaded, in seconds, times 10.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the java-doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the method [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) it gives you the current time in nano seconds. Also since the field `timeStarted` is `static` it is assigned when the class `Time` is loaded into the JVM therefore that field saves the time when the class was loaded. The method `getTime` just calculates the difference from the current time with `timeStarted` and multiplies it by `10E-9` to convert it from nano to seconds, this value represents the that passed since the class was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

From [System docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()):

```
nanoTime()
Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.
```

Your first `println` gives you the time, in **nanoseconds**, that the variable `timeStarted` was assigned (in this case a very large number).

Your second `println` gives you the time, in **seconds**, between the start of your code and the calling of `getTime()`. This 2nd value is in seconds because it is multiplied by `10E-9`, the conversion factor from nanoseconds to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If is often the case that 'time' in a computer system is represented by a single number. The number counts the number of conceptual 'ticks' that have occurred since some initial time (i.e., the point at which the number was 0).  In this case a tick is 1 nanosecond -- I don't mean to imply that the clock is actually ticking at that rate, the number representing the time could (say) be incremented by 100 every 100 nS.

Thus, if you have two times of this type, the number of ticks between them can be determined by simple subtraction.

To time events, you get the current time before and after the event, and calculate the difference. It's not necessary to know what the initial time 'means' in order to use such timing. You just treat the time as a number.